# Will updating ID column manually harm the database?

Tags: database, postgresql, activerecord, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

My question is exactly as described above

My case is:

I need to migrate old server data to a new server

I have extracted all the required data on excel sheets

Example of an entry of an article

id 200

title whatever

linked_item_id 1400

Many deletion occured as filtering to the old data so it's not starting from 1 anymore

That's why when i import this data on the new server, I'll need the article to have ID 200 and the linked item to be 1400 so i can associate it on the new system using xlsx importer with a custom methods

After that, normal and proper usage for the DB should be happening through the app (This is to import the data only)

3 Questions here which i need the answer for:

1- I just want to make sure that updating the ID after saving the record won't harm the DB, will it ?

2- Will that affect the performance of loading the relations ?, as the foreign_keys isn't entered properly

3- Assuming i have newly initiated DB and i added first record and it got ID 1, then i manually updated the record to be ID 200
Will the next record take 201 or 2 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use the GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY constraint on the id column of the new database.

Comment: Sorry but i can't see this is helpful, I already have multiple ideas on how to import the data, i just have 3 questions that i want to know, to be sure that i'm not doing something wrong

Comment: Thanks for your answer after all @JonGuiton :)

Comment: I usually rename the id field to migrate as "old_id" and i used it just for the migration of the old data. This way you should not have to worry for any of yours questions, once the task is done I work with a new and totally standard "id" autoincrementable and well indexed.